# Fetch from Google API inside action creator (React + Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets

I'm trying to implement [Google Quickstart Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js). The example is a plain HTML file.

I'm using react, I've made an action call `fetchData` from where I'll be dispatching the actions (I'm using Thunk so I'll be dispatching LOADING, SUCCESS and FAILURE actions).

Thing is, in the example, it includes a JS file with a callback when it's loaded, then it calls a local function. How do I implement this in the action creator. The whole JS file looks like this:

```
import { FETCH_DATA } from './actions-types';

const fetchData = async () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: `${FETCH_DATA}_LOADING` });

  //fetch from google api
}
```

Comment: I couldn't get your requirement fully. Do you want to call an API inside? You can use await for fetching. And once you got the response, dispatch success action

Comment: Let me know if your requirement is different.

Comment: What I mean is that, in the example, it loads the Google API script using `<script>` tag, and it has a callback that calls a load function, how do I resemble that inside this JS function?

Comment: can you share the example link?

Comment: You want to load and initialize the API client library with sign-in state listeners from a Redux action?  This is likely something you'd initialize when your app initializes and you would manage login and data states of the API with Redux actions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a function that will make the dispatch.
It'll be something like this:

```js
export default function fetchData() {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch({ type: `${FETCH_DATA}_LOADING` });
    try {
      const dataYouNeed = await fetchGoogleAPI();
      // do something with dataYouNeed
      const payload = { the payload you need to save in state }
      dispatch({ type: `${FETCH_DATA}_SUCCESS`, payload });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      dispatch({ type: `${FETCH_DATA}_FAILURE`, payload });
    }
}
```

Alternative:

Since you are using Thunk, I recommend you this package: [redux-promise-middleware](https://github.com/pburtchaell/redux-promise-middleware), it will dispatch `FETCH_DATA_PENDING`, `FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED` and `FETCH_DATA_FAIL` for you, and will make your life much easier.

```js
export default function fetchData() {
  return async dispatch => {
    const payload = () async => {
      const dataYouNeed = await fetchGoogleAPI();
      // do something with dataYouNeed
      return dataYouNeed
    }
    dispatch({ type: FETCH_DATA, payload });
}
```

The main change in the code above, it's because when you dispatch a promise payload, the middleware will handle the PENDING, FULFILLED, and FAIL status for you.
Then you can use `FETCH_DATA_PENDING`, `FETCH_DATA_FULFILLED` and `FETCH_DATA_FAIL` inside your reducer, because redux-promise-middleware will provide them for you.